# Adding data to CArray gives error "cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'"

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a structure called `PERSONS` and then I have defined a type `CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray, PERSONS*> PersonsTable;`

```
struct Persons { ... };
typedef CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray, PERSONS*> PersonsTable;
```

Later in the code I try to make a `PersonTable` `CArray`:

```
void CArrayTesting()
{
    CArray<PersonsTable, PersonsTable> oCArr;
    oCArr.SetSize(3);
    PersonsTable perTableA;
    PersonsTable perTableB;
    PersonsTable perTableC;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i < 3)      addPerson(perTableA, i);
        else if (i < 8) addPerson(perTableB, i);
        else            addPerson(perTableC, i);
    }
    oCArr.Add(perTableA);
    oCArr.Add(perTableB);
    oCArr.Add(perTableC);
    for (int nArrCnt = 0; nArrCnt < oCArr.GetSize(); nArrCnt++)
        for (int i = 0; i < oCArr.ElementAt(nArrCnt).GetSize(); i++)
        {
            cout<<"Table "<< nArrCnt << " - " << oCArr.ElementAt(nArrCnt)[i]->nID << endl;
            delete oCArr.ElementAt(nArrCnt)[i];
        }
}
```

The `addPerson()` function adds data to `PersonTable`.

However, this causes an error during the compilation: `cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject` . The error appears to be related to `oCArr.Add()`, because it gets 'fixed' when I delete the respected rows.

Why does the error appear? How can I fix it? And how does CArray work?

Comment: What is the difference between `Persons` and `PERSONS`?

Comment: Did the error message tell you, which private member of class `CObject` cannot be accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error boils down to class `CPtrArray` not defining a copy constructor, which your code uses when adding to `oCArr`.  The compiler generated default copy constructor will try to call the copy constructor for `CObject`, which is declared `private`.

You should probably add the elements into `oCArr` directly, rather than adding them to local variables then making copies.

Answer (score 1):

1201 is correct, and it's a massive headache. If you're forced to use the MFC collections, you could derive from them and create custom copy constructors/assignment operators. (and move + initializer_list) The array collections have a Copy function you can use to make life simple.

```
class CPtrArrayEx : public CPtrArray
{
public:
    CPtrArrayEx() = default;
    CPtrArrayEx(CPtrArrayEx const& rhs)
    {
        Copy(rhs);
    }

    CPtrArrayEx& operator=(CPtrArrayEx const& rhs)
    {
        if (this != &rhs)
            Copy(rhs);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: *"it's a massive headache"* - Only, if you do not understand, why things are the way they are. The copy constructor is declared `private`, to save developers from doing the wrong thing. In the great majority of cases, copying a container with pointers to objects needs custom logic (e.g. storing pointers to copies). If you want your copy to point to the same objects and don't want to implement that custom logic yourself, use a `CArray` with a `std::shared_ptr` instead of `CPtrArray`.

Comment: I understand why they did it - it doesn't make me feel any less annoyed when I go to do trivial tasks (copy/assign/return) with a CArray<int>, CList<NonCObjectType>, etc and they don't work.